# Вытащить информацию из SQLite на новое Activity

Tags: java, android, listview, sqlite

Здравствуйте!
У меня есть 3 класса: 
В **DB** создаю базу данных, записи добавляются прямо из приложения.
В **MainActivity** по данным из базы создаю ListView, заполняемый с помощью CursorLoader.
По идее, в зависимости от выбранного объекта из ListView запускается новое activity, которое отображает данные из БД по этому объекту. За это должен отвечать третий класс - **OneEvent**.

Реализовать открытие нового activity у меня получилось, вопрос - как вытащить информацию БД на этот activity?

Коды классов:
**MainActivity**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.ListView;


import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final int CM_DELETE_ID = 1;
    ListView lvData;
    DB db;
    SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter;
    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // открываем подключение к БД
        db = new DB(this);
        db.open();

        // формируем столбцы сопоставления
        String[] from = new String[] { DB.COLUMN_TITLE, DB.COLUMN_DATE, DB.COLUMN_TIME };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tvTextTitle, R.id.tvTextDate, R.id.tvTextTime };

        // создаем адаптер и настраиваем список
        scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0);
        lvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvData);
        lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);

        // добавляем контекстное меню к списку
        registerForContextMenu(lvData);

        // создаем лоадер для чтения данных
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

       lvData.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "itemClick: position = " + position + ", id = " + id);

             Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , OneEvent.class);
               startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
         });

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Добавить событие");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        sb.append("Item Menu");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddEvent.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (data == null) {return;}
        String title = data.getStringExtra("title");
        String date = data.getStringExtra("date");
        String time = data.getStringExtra("time");
        db.addRec(title, date, time);
        getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();
    }

    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, CM_DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.delete_record);
    }

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == CM_DELETE_ID) {
            // получаем из пункта контекстного меню данные по пункту списка
            AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                    .getMenuInfo();
            // извлекаем id записи и удаляем соответствующую запись в БД
            db.delRec(acmi.id);
            // получаем новый курсор с данными
            getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // закрываем подключение при выходе
        db.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bndl) {
        return new MyCursorLoader(this, db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        scAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

    }

    static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {

        DB db;

        public MyCursorLoader(Context context, DB db) {
            super(context);
            this.db = db;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            Cursor cursor = db.getAllData();
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return cursor;
        }

    }
}
```

**OneEvent**

```
package ru.startandroid.p000111testing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
/**
 * Created by F.Slowpoke on 03.04.2016.
 */
public class OneEvent extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView tvEventTitle, tvEventDate, tvEventTime;
    int id = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.one_event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
}
```

**DB**

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
/**
 * Created by F.Slowpoke on 02.04.2016.
 */
public class DB {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "mydb";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DB_TABLE = "mytab";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String COLUMN_DATE = "date";
    public static final String COLUMN_TIME = "time";

    private static final String DB_CREATE =
            "create table " + DB_TABLE + "(" +
                    COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                    COLUMN_TITLE + " text, " +
                    COLUMN_DATE + " text, " +
                    COLUMN_TIME + " text" +
                    ");";

    private final Context mCtx;


    private DBHelper mDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDB;


    public DB(Context ctx) {
        mCtx = ctx;
    }

    // открыть подключение
    public void open() {
        mDBHelper = new DBHelper(mCtx, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        mDB = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    // закрыть подключение
    public void close() {
        if (mDBHelper!=null) mDBHelper.close();
    }

    // получить все данные из таблицы DB_TABLE
    public Cursor getAllData() {
        return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, "_id DESC");
    }

    // добавить запись в DB_TABLE
    public void addRec(String tit, String dat, String tim) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_TITLE, tit);
        cv.put(COLUMN_DATE, dat);
        cv.put(COLUMN_TIME, tim);
        mDB.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    // удалить запись из DB_TABLE
    public void delRec(long id) {
        mDB.delete(DB_TABLE, COLUMN_ID + "=" + id, null);
    }

    // класс по созданию и управлению БД
    private class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DBHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
                        int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        // создаем и заполняем БД
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(DB_CREATE);

            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
                cv.put(COLUMN_TITLE, "sometext " + i);
                cv.put(COLUMN_DATE, "sometext " + i);
                cv.put(COLUMN_TIME, "sometext " + i);
                db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Передаете из первого активити во второе ид записи, информацию о которой нужно отобразить.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, OneEvent.class);
intent.putExtra("id", id);
```

Во втором активити получаете этот ид, и загружаете из БД информацию по этому ид.

```
long id = getIntent().getLongExtra("id", -1);
Cursor cursor = mDb.query("tableName", null, "_id = " + id, null, null, null, null);
```

И дальше из курсора вытягиваете информацию, которую нужно отобразить.

UPD: обновленный класс DB

```
public class DB {

    public Cursor getById(long id) {
        return mDb.query("tableName", null, "_id = " + id, null, null, null, null);
    }
}
```

Вызов:

```
DB db = new DB(context);
...
Cursor cursor = db.getById(id);
```

Comment: Я сделала как Вы посоветовали, но студия ругается на то, что mDB.query приватный в классе DB, а не публичный

Comment: @FatSlowpoke сделайте его обычным публичным классом

Comment: Сделала, теперь ругается на db.getAllData

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня query реализован внутри getAllData

Comment: @FatSlowpoke тогда, по вашей логике, надо в классе DB сделать метод getById(long id), в котором реализовать метод с mDb.query(), и в нужном месте вызывать его. Отредактировал ответ.

Comment: Тогда, получается, когда я отображаю информацию, это выглядит так:

Comment: Cursor cursor = db.getById(id);

       String title = getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_TITLE));
       tvEventTitle.setText(String.valueOf(title));
       String date = getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_DATE));
       tvEventDate.setText(String.valueOf(date));
       String time = getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_TIME));
       tvEventTime.setText(String.valueOf(time));